# squid: allow only certain youtube videos (solved for FF, not working on IE)

Tags: squid

At my job, I'm not the systadmin but a linux programmer.  But once in a while the sysadmins (who generally aren't that knowledgeable about linux) ask me for help.  Today the sysadmin asked me to allow access to only specified YouTube videos with squid v2.6 (why not 2.7?  probably because that's what several predecessors ago installed ...)

I put added lines to squid.conf to allow that one video, then I watched access.log for more URLs that got TCP_DENIED.  Eventually I had them all allowed, and that one video played.

```
acl youtube_allow url_regex ^http://www.youtube.com/v/a17SaWJwBVM$
acl youtube_allow url_regex ^http://www.youtube.com/crossdomain.xml$
acl youtube_allow url_regex ^http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info\?
acl youtube_allow url_regex ^http://s.youtube.com
acl youtube_allow url_regex ^http://www.youtube.com/ptracking\?
acl youtube_allow url_regex ^http://o-o.preferred.*c.youtube.com/videoplayback
http_access allow youtube_allow
acl youtube_domains dstdomain .youtube.com .googlevideo.com
http_access deny youtube_domains
```

But on internet explorer 8, http://www.youtube.com/v/a17SaWJwBVM displays a blank window, and nothing turns up in access.log as DENIED.  Aside from forcing everyone to use FF (not a bad idea, but possibly beyond our abilities) is there any way to make this viewable by IE users?

Note that we're not trying to cache the video.  On FF all the youtube URLs appear as TCP_MISS and that's fine.

Comment: try installing fiddler on a computer with internet explorer. fiddler will show you the complete http request and the raw responses.

Comment: I installed fiddler, and all I found in IE was that the original URL http://www.youtube.com/v/a17SaWJwBVM redirected to youtube.googleapis.com, which it fetched twice for some reason, but both seem to have succeeded (response 200).  Anything else I should look for?

Comment: PS. I tried fidler on FF and saw that it also redirected to googleapis.com but then it fetched the other URLs that I had previously seen denied in access.log

Comment: did you see anything denied or failed in fiddler on IE?

Comment: Are you certain you have completely cleared the IE cache?  You might want to make sure you completely clear the browser cache, and then completely kill the IE process so any in-memory caches are also wiped.

Comment: no denies or fails - no errors displayed in IE, no denies in fiddler or acccess.log.  I cleared the cache, exited, saw there was no IE process running in task manager, restarted IE, and the only difference was that it fetched the favicon.

Comment: Out of desparation I had the sysadmin reboot the firewall and it's OK now, so it wasn't IE or squid's fault.  But thanks to all for their suggestions, sorry to have wasted your time.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible that you are only watching what is currently in your webcache.

As you may be aware any proxy administrator on any network **SHOULD** acknowledge nocache headers etc... As I remember Youtube states nocache... It's simple netiquette.

If you are a home user simply install the FlashGot Addon in Firefox and save the file locally.